# Why does my function add an extra dash to this URL? ( PHP:Regex)

Tags: php, regex

```
function convert($raw) {

    $new = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $raw);

    return $new;

}
```

The functon turns "a boy" into "a-boy-" when i run it, but i want "a-boy" how do I modify the regex to take care of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: you had a typo. It should be `return $new;` instead of `return $raw;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert($raw) {

    $new = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $raw);
    $new = rtrim($new,'-');
    return $new;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out it works fine**

```
function convert($raw) {

    $new = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", " ", $raw);

    return $new;

}

$data ="a - boy";
echo convert($data);
```